# Convert sql query to dql query in symfony 3

Tags: sql, sql-server, symfony, dql

I have a SQL query I want to convert it to a dql query in symfony 3.4, 
this is the SQL query:

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM chat c INNER JOIN (
  SELECT idsender, MAX(created) created 
  FROM chat
  WHERE idreceiver = 2 OR idsender = 2
  GROUP BY idsender 
) t ON t.idsender = c.idsender AND t.created = c.created 
WHERE c.idreceiver = 2
```

This is my attempt:

```
    public function findAllChatBox($idreceiver,$idsender)
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
                'SELECT c FROM offer Bundle:chat c WHERE  c.idreceiver = :idreceiver  AND idsender=:idsender'
            )
            ->groupBy('c.idsender')
            ->join('t ON t.idsender = c.idsender AND t.created = c.created 
WHERE c.idreceiver =: idreceiver')
            ->setParameter('idreceiver',$idreceiver)
            ->setParameter('idsender',$idsender)
            ->getResult();
    }
```

But I had a syntax error, any suggestions please?

> syntax error here 'join('t ON t.idsender = c.idsender AND t.created = c.created WHERE c.idreceiver =: idreceiver')'

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: syntax error here 
'join('t ON t.idsender = c.idsender AND t.created = c.created 
WHERE c.idreceiver =: idreceiver')' i dont know wher exactly honestly

Comment: Is this the exact error? It pretty vague.

Comment: If you want DQL, why don't you write DQL instead of this query builder mixup (`join` has a very different signature, doesn't exist on Query, also, there is no `t` in your "DQL" query). Try fresh from `createQuery("your sql query")`, then start replacing column names with property names and table names with entity names (plus alias)